# How do I best communicate that my website is shutting down?

Tags: domains, management, community-management

I am at a crossroads. I have received an offer for my domain name that I am likely going to accept.

It's something that has not been under active development for a long while, but still has some active users. The website also has a mobile app with some active users. I considered buying an alternate domain but I don't think it's going to be possible for me to continue with the project once I do this. The project has 0 revenue.

How can I best communicate that the site is shutting down, both from a messaging and also PR standpoint?

Any insight would be very valuable to me.

Comment: Make a 'Officially Closed' layout and upload it to your site and do the same thing with the phone app.

Answer (score 4):

Here is [a blog post that Dan Blumenthal (a friend of mine) wrote about shutting down a long time project and website](http://dandreamsofcoding.com/2013/08/07/shutting-down-a-dream/).  I think that he handles the situation well.

- Post about the shutdown fully explaining your reasoning on a blog so that people looking for the resource can figure out what happened after the fact.
- Email your users explaining the situation
- Allow a grace period for your users to retrieve any data from your system.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can consider to sell your domain name under the condition that the new owner will place a good looking message about your shutting down and a link to how to find your new domain and your apps:

- a message in your wordings on his front page (or maybe somewhere else
  too),
- with your (old/new) logo for better recognition,
- in the px dimensions and font-size you prefer,
- during a certain period (1 year, 1.5 year?),
- and a juridical waterproof penalty if the new owner doesn't do it or
  removes the message before the period is ended.

Answer (score -1):

1) Buy a new domain.
2) Email all your users your new domain.